# How to find the matrix dimensions using OpenCV from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I am trying to extract the dimensions of a matrix from an image which is like a tic-tac-toe with a dimension of N x M. How do I find the dimension of the matrix using OpenCV. There are many images with varying matrix dimensions like 3x3, 4x4, 4x5, 5x6, etc... How to find them all

I tried to use contours and didn't know how to proceed in finding the dimensions. The above is an example image[image]

Comment: Detect and count horizontal/vertical long straight lines.

Comment: just count the number of white connected components

Comment: @fana how to do that

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample code which detects the vertical lines.
(This code is in C++, but I think you can see what it's doing.)

```cpp
int main()
{
    //Load Image
    cv::Mat Img = cv::imread( "Grid.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( Img.empty() )return 0;

    //
    // 1D Hough-Transform ( Vertical Black Line Detection )
    //

    std::vector<unsigned int> VotingSpace( Img.cols, 0 );
    {//Voting
        constexpr unsigned char BinalizeThresh = 128;
        for( int y=0; y<Img.rows; ++y )
        {
            const unsigned char *p = Img.ptr<unsigned char>( y );
            for( int x=0; x<Img.cols; ++x, ++p )
            {
                if( *p < BinalizeThresh ){  ++VotingSpace[x];   }
            }
        }
    }
    {//Detection and Visualize the Result
        const unsigned int DetectionThresh = Img.rows * 3 / 4;

        cv::Mat ShowImg;
        cv::cvtColor( Img, ShowImg, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR );

        int nDetectedLines = 0;
        unsigned int Denom = 0;
        unsigned int Nume = 0;
        for( int x=0; x<Img.rows; ++x )
        {
            unsigned int V = VotingSpace[x];
            if( V > DetectionThresh )
            {
                Denom += V;
                Nume += x * V;
            }
            else if( Denom>0 )
            {
                double Band_Center_x = (double)Nume / (double)Denom;
                std::cout << "Line Position x = " << Band_Center_x << std::endl;

                Nume = Denom = 0;
                ++nDetectedLines;

                {//Draw line to visualize
                    int Rounded_Center = cvRound( Band_Center_x );
                    cv::line( ShowImg, cv::Point(Rounded_Center,0), cv::Point(Rounded_Center,Img.rows), cv::Scalar(0,0,255) );
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "nDetectedLines = " << nDetectedLines << std::endl;
        cv::imshow( "ShowImg", ShowImg );
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

4 vertical lines can be detected from the your example image. Result output is :

```
Line Position x = 25.5
Line Position x = 296
Line Position x = 567
Line Position x = 837.5
nDetectedLines = 4
```

Therefore, we can estimate the dimension in the x direction to be 3.

Do the same for the horizontal line to complete your work.

Comment: This should do the trick. Hough transform is robust and well suited for this problem.

Comment: Since the black lines are bold, I estimated the x-position of each lines by weighted average using the vote value as the weight.

Comment: What if the box contains any numbers or letters

Comment: How can I then detect the dimensions

Comment: @DHANUSHT: then you should have mentioned that in your question. Maybe try to find contours and paint their bounding boxes white ? that should remove everything inside the fields.

Comment: @fana can you give an example with a python code. Currently I'm working with elixir Evision to complete the task

Comment: I think that the effect of letters can be avoided by using the difference in the number of votes and the equal spacing of grid lines.

Comment: I don't know python.